# Tool for searching spells with different filter criteria

Tags: dnd-5e, tools

Is there a tool for searching spells using various filter criteria? Besides the usual class, level, school criteria, these are the sort of filters I have in mind:

- If the spell requires the caster to perform a spell attack.
- If the spell allows the target to make a saving throw and, if so, which save.
- If the spell requires concentration to maintain.
- If the spell requires expensive components and, if so, if they are consumed.